# Javascript: How to use array value as key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, key

console.log of an array ($myarray) returns this:

```
[ RowDataPacket { name: 'Foo', value: 1 },
  RowDataPacket { name: 'Bar', value: 3 } ]
```

How can I convert the array to make it possible to have the name available as key?

At the end console.log($myarray[Bar]) should return: 3

Comment: There is an example of this exact scenario in [Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/187/arrays/2459/reducing-values#t=20170508145757183778)

Comment: What is `RowDataPacket`? How are you constructing this array? Try providing some code in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: The RowDataPacket comes from the result of a mysql return. https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is to convert your array into an object. Use the `reduce()` function to iterate over each item in the array, process it and mutate the accumulator object that will be returned as the resulting object.

```
$myarray.reduce(function(obj, item) {
    obj[item.name] = item.value;
    return obj;
}, {});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: I've given you an upvote because your code does _seem_ to work but could you add some detail on what it's doing and if possible why it works.

Comment: Generally code-only answers are less helpful than they could be with added explanation.

Comment: Code first, explain later!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can search using filter and return 0th element
like

```
var array = [ { name: 'Foo', value: 1 },
  { name: 'Bar', value: 3 } ]

var result =  array.filter(i=>i.name=='Bar')[0]
console.log(result)
```